# Capture keyPressEvent in minimized PyQt application

Tags: python, pyqt, keyboard-shortcuts, trayicon

I am trying to write an error reporting application and would like to keep it as a tray icon for the most part - but the idea is to maximize it with a specific key combination (e.g. "Ctrl+Alt+H", or something like it).

Comment: You can't do this with standard qt/pyqt, so you'll need a third-party library, such as [pygs](https://github.com/Asvel/pygs).

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812617/pyqt-listen-for-systemwide-key-and-mouse-events

Answer (score 0):

Look like not possible as is. But I found that. It should be a start of an answer for you:

http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/tip/qxtglobalshortcut.html

[How to detect global key sequence press in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193038/how-to-detect-global-key-sequence-press-in-qt)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply, I was looking deeper into some of the codes I had in my repo and found out this - 
https://sourceforge.net/p/pyhook/wiki/PyHook_Tutorial/

This is specifically for windows but saw pyxhook for linux

http://jeffhoogland.blogspot.in/2014/10/pyhook-for-linux-with-pyxhook.html

Tried the windows version and it is working like a charm, need to customise that though. Have to the linux version as well